# Можно ли передать ajax'ом и 'FormData()' и 'обычную' переменную?

Tags: jquery, ajax, javascript, php

Делаю ajax-загрузку фотографий. Сами фотографии передаю в скрипт загнав из в FormData(). Но кроме того нужно передать еще одну переменную - id альбома, куда их поместить.
Как передать в скрипт и список фотографий и id, за один запрос, и как с скрипте их использовать?

Кусок JS формирующий данные с фотографиями:

```
jQuery.each($('#pht_file')[0].files, function(i, file) {
    data.append('file-'+i, file); });
```

Php скрипт:

```
foreach ($_FILES as list ($key => $value)) {
 move_uploaded_file($value['tmp_name'], "tmp/".$value['name']);
 }
```

Как тудыть добавить левую переменную со значением? Единственная идея - поставить первой парой, а сами фотографии будут идти со второй.

Comment: Да, можно https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Добавляем данные в FormData.

```
data.append('name', 'value');
```

На сервере

```
$_POST['name']
```

там будет строка "value"